# I input image from form in db with mongoose, and return that image to product on my page, but it is not displayed. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudinary, formidable

I send the picture to the server, and there it is undefined, but the url loaded on cloudinary and there is a picture.

JS submitting data from a form and creating an element

```
let products = []; // Глобальний масив для зберігання продуктів

function getAndShowAllProducts() {
  let sortedProducts = [...products]; // Копіюємо продукти для сортування
  //alert(products[0].productImage)
  // Сортування за ціною, якщо чекбокс вибраний
  const sortCheckbox = document.getElementById("sortcheckbox");
  if (sortCheckbox.checked) {
    sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => a.productLan - b.productLan);
  }

  const dataContainer = document.querySelector(".dataContainer");
  dataContainer.innerHTML = "";

  sortedProducts.forEach((product) => {
    let productCard = document.createElement("div");
    productCard.classList.add("element");

    productCard.innerHTML = `
      <div class="element-data">
        <img src="${product.productImage}" class="element-img">
        <div class="element-name">${product.productName}</div>
        <p class="element-text">Процесор: <span class="element-volume">${product.productProc}</span></p> 
        <p class="element-text">Кількість слотів для дисків: <span class="element-material">${product.productDisk}</span></p>
        <p class="element-text">Кількість оперативної пам'яті: <span class="element-material">${product.productOp}</span></p> 
        <p class="element-text">Ціна: <span class="element-material">${product.productLan}</span></p>  
      </div>
      <div class="element-footer">
        <button class="edit-button" onclick="modifyModalToEdit('${product._id}', '${product.productName}', '${product.productProc}', '${product.productDisk}', '${product.productOp}', '${product.productLan}', '${product.productImage}', '${product.cloudinaryPublicId}')">Edit</button><span> </span>
        <button class="delete-button" onclick="removeProduct('${product._id}', '${product.cloudinaryPublicId}')">Delete</button>
      </div>
    `;

    dataContainer.appendChild(productCard);
  });
}

// Отримання продуктів з бази даних
async function fetchProductsFromDatabase() {
  await fetch("/products")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
  products = data
  getAndShowAllProducts();
  });
}

// Обробник події натискання на кнопку сортування
function handleSortCheckboxChange() {
  getAndShowAllProducts(); // Відображаємо продукти з оновленим сортуванням
}

// Додавання слухача подій на зміну стану чекбокса
const sortCheckbox = document.getElementById("sortcheckbox");
sortCheckbox.addEventListener("change", handleSortCheckboxChange);

// Виклик функції fetchProductsFromDatabase() для отримання продуктів з бази даних
fetchProductsFromDatabase();

function collectFormData() {
  const productForm = document.forms["productForm"];
  const productImageInput = document.getElementById("productImage");
  const productImage = productImageInput.files[0]; // Отримання вибраного файлу зображення
  const cloudinaryPublicId = document.getElementById("cloudinaryPublicId").value; // Отримання значення поля cloudinaryPublicId
  let formData = new FormData(productForm);
  formData.append("productImage", productImage);
  formData.append("cloudinaryPublicId", cloudinaryPublicId);
  console.log(formData.get("productImage"));
  productForm.reset();
  return formData;
}

async function sendData() {
  await fetch('/products', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: collectFormData()
  });
}

async function modalpush() {
  if (valid() && validImg()) {
    await sendData();
    fetchProductsFromDatabase(); // Отримати та відобразити оновлений список продуктів
    Modaleclose();
  }
}

async function removeProduct(_id, cloudinaryPublicId) {
  const deleteParams = {
    _id: _id,
    cloudinaryPublicId: cloudinaryPublicId,
  };

  await fetch(`/products/${_id}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(deleteParams),
  });

  fetchProductsFromDatabase();
}

function modifyModalToEdit(_id, productName, productProc, productDisk, productOp, productLan, productImage, cloudinaryPublicId) {
  document.getElementById("modalcont").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("greybg").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("text-h")[0].innerText = "Edit NAS";
  document.getElementById("submit-btn").innerText = "Update";
  document.getElementById('formImage').setAttribute("src", productImage);
  document.getElementById("js-input-model-edit").value = productName;
  document.getElementById("js-proc-edit").value = productProc;
  document.getElementById("js-disk-edit").value = productDisk;
  document.getElementById("js-op-edit").value = productOp;
  document.getElementById("js-lan-edit").value = productLan;
  document.getElementById("productId").value = _id;
  document.getElementById('oldImagePath').value = productImage;
  document.getElementById("oldCloudinaryPublicId").value = cloudinaryPublicId;
}

// Виклик функції getAndShowAllProducts() після її оголошення
getAndShowAllProducts();

// Обробник події натискання на кнопку пошуку
const searchButton = document.querySelector(".green-button");
searchButton.addEventListener("click", handleSearch);

function handleSearch() {
  const searchField = document.querySelector(".searchfield");
  const searchTerm = searchField.value.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (searchTerm === "") {
    // Якщо поле пошуку порожнє, відображаємо всі продукти
    getAndShowAllProducts();
    return;
  }

  const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) =>
    product.productName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );

  if (filteredProducts.length > 0) {
    // Якщо є знайдені продукти, відображаємо їх
    const dataContainer = document.querySelector(".dataContainer");
    dataContainer.innerHTML = "";

    filteredProducts.forEach((product) => {
      let productCard = document.createElement("div");
      productCard.classList.add("element");

      productCard.innerHTML = `
        <div class="element-data">
          <img src="${product.productImage}" class="element-img">
          <div class="element-name">${product.productName}</div>
          <p class="element-text">Процесор: <span class="element-volume">${product.productProc}</span></p> 
          <p class="element-text">Кількість слотів для дисків: <span class="element-material">${product.productDisk}</span></p>
          <p class="element-text">Кількість оперативної пам'яті: <span class="element-material">${product.productOp}</span></p> 
          <p class="element-text">Ціна: <span class="element-material">${product.productLan}</span></p>  
        </div>
        <div class="element-footer">
          <button class="edit-button" onclick="modifyModalToEdit('${product._id}', '${product.productName}', '${product.productProc}', '${product.productDisk}', '${product.productOp}', '${product.productLan}', '${product.productImage}', '${product.cloudinaryPublicId}')">Edit</button><span> </span>
          <button class="delete-button" onclick="removeProduct('${product._id}', '${product.cloudinaryPublicId}')">Delete</button>
        </div>
      `;

      dataContainer.appendChild(productCard);
    });
  } else {
    // Якщо немає знайдених продуктів, відображаємо повідомлення
    const dataContainer = document.querySelector(".dataContainer");
    dataContainer.innerHTML = "<p>No products found.</p>";
  }
}
```

Backend on node.js Express

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const Product = require('./back/modelschema');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');


const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: 'dk0ktbhvw',
  api_key: '437137168384151',
  api_secret: 'w0Be7apM29LBmFOltXAkuEVuZ5I',
  secure: true,
});

const mongoDB = "mongodb+srv://taps73r:povroznik05@cluster0.rx59bw7.mongodb.net/";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("З'єднання з БД встановлено");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  error ? console.log(error) : console.log(`Сервер запущено на порту ${PORT}`);
});

// Отримання всіх продуктів
app.get("/products", (req, res) => {
  Product.find({})
    .then((products) => {
      return res.send(products);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send("Помилка при отриманні продуктів");
    });
});

// Видалення продукту
app.delete("/products/:id", (req, res) => {
  const productId = req.params.id;

  Product.findByIdAndRemove(productId)
    .then((product) => {
      if (!product) {
        return res.status(404).send("Продукт не знайдено");
      }

      // Видалення зображення з Cloudinary
      cloudinary.uploader.destroy(product.cloudinaryPublicId, { invalidate: true }, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

      res.send("Продукт успішно видалено");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send("Помилка при видаленні продукту");
    });
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const form = formidable({
    multiples: true,
    keepExtensions: true,
    uploadDir: __dirname + '/uploads' // Задайте каталог для збереження завантажених файлів
  });

  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error parsing the files");
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: "Fail",
        message: "There was an error parsing the files",
        error: err,
      });
    }

    const { productId, productName, productProc, productDisk, productOp, productLan, oldCloudinaryPublicId, oldImagePath } = fields;
    const { productImage } = files;

    const productInfo = {
      productName,
      productProc,
      productDisk,
      productOp,
      productLan,
    };

    if (!productImage || !productImage.name) {
      // Якщо картинка не мінялася - додаємо в об'єкт старі поля
      productInfo.productImage = oldImagePath;
      productInfo.cloudinaryPublicId = oldCloudinaryPublicId;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(productInfo.productImage));
      saveDataToDB(productId, productInfo, res);
    } else {
      // Якщо картинка мінялася - додаємо в об'єкт нові поля
      const tempPath = productImage.path;
      const targetPath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + productImage.name;

      fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error moving the uploaded file");
          return res.status(500).send("Помилка при переміщенні завантаженого файлу");
        }

        cloudinary.uploader.upload(targetPath, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.warn(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Помилка при завантаженні зображення");
          }

          productInfo.productImage = result.url;
          productInfo.cloudinaryPublicId = result.public_id;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(productInfo.productImage));
          saveDataToDB(productId, productInfo, res);
          // Видаляємо стару картинку в Cloudinary
          cloudinary.uploader.destroy(oldCloudinaryPublicId, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

router.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  Product.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(docs);
    } else {
      console.warn('Error in retrieving product list:', err);
    }
  });
});

const jsonParser = express.json();
router.delete("/:id", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  const productId = req.params.id;
  cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.cloudinaryPublicId);
  Product.findByIdAndDelete(productId, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
});

function saveDataToDB(productId, data, res) {
  // Перевіряємо чи створювати новий запис в БД, чи оновлювати наявний
  if (productId == "") {
    // Створюємо новий запис БД
    Product.create(data)
      .then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Помилка при збереженні продукту");
      });
  } else {
    // Оновлюємо наявний запис БД
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, data)
      .then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Помилка при оновленні продукту");
      });
  }
}

app.use("/products", router);

module.exports = router;
```

The output to the console on the server is data about the picture, the output is undefined.
Cloudinary receives a url with a picture, but on the server itself it is undefined and it is not displayed in the elements.

Comment: Is your `productImage` a file or a URL string?

Comment: <input class="file" name="productImage" type="file" id="productImage" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png"> productImage it is Id and name of input.
I input image like a file, but in db schema he is a string

Comment: I update this code on new. Because I do some edit there. But problem stay alive.
Now image on input not undefined, image now empty, I check this in terminal.

Comment: I do edit to code check function collectformdata

Comment: Try sending data with `FormData()` and not `FormData(productForm)` and append to that empty `fromData`.

Comment: there is no reason to do this. Image and other inputs are correct, but problem on server. Because when I submit data other info of product saved correctly, only image is empty

Comment: I wanted to make sure that you are sending the file correctly and not an empty file.

Comment: When using async function, it may be necessary to wait for the process execution to be completed (maybe use Promise, instead - here is a [sample code for direct upload to Cloudinary REST API](https://jsfiddle.net/eyalkt/m4wgjx05/2/)).